# Create a cache (Angular - Addin)

Tags: angular, caching, office-js, page-refresh

I'm trying to create a cache to avoid some calls on a request (API - REST).

I'm doing it with a map where keys are userId and the value the response (get from the API).

It's working, my problem is when I'm refreshing the page (more like the addin) with F5.

So the question is: What happens to elements like properties in service after a refresh? My map is clear, but why? Because refresh an addin work differently (it work as a reboot of the application)? Is it normal with Angular?

Answer (score 3):

Refreshing a page refreshes the entire Angular application. It regets the application from the server and reloads it. No data or property values are retained.

If you need to cache data on the *client* that is accessible across refreshes, you can use `localstorage`.

Comment: Thanks ! Ok, so i can't do it without localstorage.Thanks again for your time.